# Encoding changes while passing to other command?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I have a file, which I read from `test`. This file is UTF-8. It contains, in my simple example, only the Danish letter "Ø".

I then have a Python script, which reads this file, and in this example, just prints every line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

f = codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8')

for lines in f:
  print lines
```

Call this `parse.py`. Now when I run `./parse.py test` in my terminal I get the following output:

```
Ø
```

Calling instead `./parse.py test | less` gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print lines
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd8' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am certain my `test` file is 'UTF-8':

```
$ file -I test
test: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

As well as my `$LC_TYPE` being 'UTF-8'

What am I doing wrong? How do I get it to work, so that I can pass the output of `parse.py` to the next command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a problem with less, see [this article](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#intl) for some tips. Maybe changing the configuration of less will help.

> If your system supports the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode for non-ASCII text, as many modern systems do, you should either set your locale to something that includes the string "UTF-8" or "UTF8" (either uppercase or lowercase is ok), or set LESSCHARSET to "utf-8".

Ok, this wasn't the problem...so updating the answer based on the comments.
Needed to encode the string before print. [This article](http://boodebr.org/main/python/all-about-python-and-unicode#WHYNOPRINT) gives the reason, summed up: python needs to be told how to encode the unicode.

Comment: Doing `export LESSCHARSET="utf-8"` prior to running the command, does not help. I also get the same error if I do something like `./parse.py test | grep "Ø"`

Comment: Ok, then perhaps the problem is with the print function instead. Can you try encoding your output first? See [this link](http://www.python.org/~jeremy/weblog/031015.html).

Comment: Wow. That's weird. Doing `print lines.encoding('utf-8')` works. Why? If I do `print sys.stdout.encoding` I get: `UTF-8`.